# Gitignore doesn't ignore a specific folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have add this files into my gitignore file

```
public/file/*
```

and when I did git status, I still see

```
new file:   public/file/external/description.txt
new file:   public/file/external/header.txt
```

How do I make everything inside my `public/file/` ignore by git ?
How do stop that ?

Do I need to clear any caches ?

Comment: Globstar maybe: `public/file/**` Otherwise, possibly just `public/file/` to ignore the entire dir

Comment: did u try removing the * in the path ?

Comment: @CollinD : The `public/file/**` works.

Comment: I don't see them anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this either with

```
public/file/**
```

From the docs, `**` means any number of subdirectories

I think that ignoring the directory specifically rather than objects within it will work also

```
public/file/
```